# Mysql facebook style message join 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql

```
//USER TABLE
user_id name
1       ben
2       alex
3       john

//CONVERSION TABLE
c_id    user_one    user_2
1       2(alex)     1(ben)
2       2(alex)     3(john)
3       1(ben)      3(john)

//MESSAGE TABLE
m_id    c_id    send        receive     message
1       1       2(alex)     1(ben)      hi ben
2       1       2(alex)     1(ben)      ben, u there?
3       2       1(ben)      3(john)     whatever...

//QUERY 1
SELECT * FROM conversion WHERE user_one=1(ben)
OR user_two=1(ben)
```

So now i know ben have 2 conversations (one with alex another with john)

my question is
how to join 3 tables and fetch out like this

**conversation_1** - Alex(id=2) - **Last message in cv_1**(ben, u there?)

**conversationi_3** - John(id=3) - **Last message in cv_3**(whatever...)

like facebook message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea is that you have to use joins. Standard JOIN syntax will be of no help here because you cannot have OR statement in JOIN .. ON. But something like this will do the trick

```
SELECT c.c_id, u.user_id, u.name, MAX(m_id), message FROM message m, conversation c, user u
WHERE m.c_id = c.c_id
AND
(
c.user_one = u.user_id
OR
c.user_2 = u.user_id
)
GROUP BY c.c_id
```

Here we join 3 tables together, getting maximum message ID (I assume ID is auto incremental so it is safe to assume that the higher ID the older the message) and group by conversation id.  This is how we will have the oldest message and conversation details of messages where Ben (logged in user for instance) was involved

A nice article I saw somewhere on stack overflow before is http://www.khankennels.com/blog/index.php/archives/2007/04/20/getting-joins/. The current approach is INNER JOIN.

SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae6e6/14

Comment: Hi thank you very much for help, i have did the testing, it fetch out user_1's name, however what I need is the other user's name

Comment: ex. if u get into your mail box, u will see Alex:Hey u there?(last message from your converstation)